# Python : averaging over discontinuous slots (3d columns)

Tags: python

i would like to make some average over 2d axis and i think python could be handy for that but my python level is quite low (even still progressing).
My dataframe are 3 colums as is:

```
     AZ     EL      EIRP
     0.00   10.00   20.00
     0.08   10.10   21.00
     0.27   10.28   22.00
     0.34   10.45   23.00
     0.03   10.03   31.00
     0.13   10.13   32.00
     0.23   10.23   33.00
     0.33   10.33   34.00
```

So i would like to minimize size of all these data through averaging, by splitting the 2 dimensions AZ & EL in different slots of 0.1 step
In that exemple, the different slots would be then :

1. slot1 (AZ=0.05+/-0.05, EL=10.05+/-0.05): average of index 1 & 2 & 5
2. slot2 (AZ=0.15+/-0.05, EL=10.15+/-0.05): average of index 6
3. slot3 (AZ=0.25+/-0.05, EL=10.25+/-0.05): average of index 3 & 7
4. slot4 (AZ=0.35+/-0.05, EL=10.35+/-0.05): average of index 4
5. slot5 (AZ=0.35+/-0.05, EL=10.45+/-0.05): average of index 8

   [way & results of 2d averaging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osNfi.png)

First i create two lists to define the slots where the averaging will be done :

```
groupaz=np.arange(0,0.5,0.1).tolist()
groupel=np.arange(10,10.5,0.1).tolist()
```

after defining columns name as is :

```
az=df["az"]
el=df["el"]
eirp=df["eirp"]
```

then i use some "for" that works well but that would be quite long for lots of data and i'm sure that python could do more efficient, maybe by using groupby function...? that i don't succeed using it

```
for AZi in groupaz:
    for ELi in groupel:
        AZ0=AZi+epsilon
        EL0=ELi+epsilon
        boolaz=(df.az>=AZ0-epsilon) & (df.az<=AZ0+epsilon)
        boolel=(df.el>=EL0-epsilon) & (df.el<=EL0+epsilon)
        boolazel=boolaz & boolel
        liste_azel_eirp_mean=df.loc[boolazel,:].eirp.mean()
        if str(liste_azel_eirp_mean)!="nan":
              print (AZ0," ",EL0," ",liste_azel_eirp_mean)
```

Thanks for any of you that could help me.
Regards